# How to use Keras LSTM on high dimensional (video) input data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have data x `(samples,frames,sizeX,sizeY,rgbchannel)` of dimensions `(90, 10, 480, 640, 3)` which represent dataset of videos, I am trying to apply Keras LSTM to classify it. As per my understanding in `input_shape` of LSTM we pass `timesteps` and `features` which if I understand correctly should be `timesteps=10` and `features=3` i.e `480, 640, 3`.

The output data y is of dimensions `(90, 1)` representing either 1 or 0; following is the model I am training

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 
from tensorflow import keras

model = tf.keras.Sequential() 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=32, input_shape=(10, 3), activation="relu")) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation="relu"))  
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")) 

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')

model.fit(x, y, epochs=500)
```

But it is throwing error on model.fit

```
Error when checking input: expected lstm_16_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (90, 10, 480, 640, 3)
```

Comment: I think you are looking for [ConvLSTM2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ConvLSTM2D).

Comment: wrap `480, 640, 3` into a tuple maybe, --> (90,10,tuple)

Comment: Thankyou @Frightera so much! I was stuck on it for weeks, What you have suggested is the correct way to go.

Comment: @datdinhquoc that did not worked, instead got an error.
"Error converting shape to a TensorShape: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'."